# PHP Синтаксис при генерации HTML

Tags: php, html, html5

Уважаемые, подскажите, что не так с синтаксисом при формировании html. Вот такой код

```
<td class="table__cell table__row-item">
            <?php
            for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
                $myClassName = "table__star";
                if( ($number<10) && ( $x>$number ) ){
                    $myClassName = "table__star disactive";
                }
                if( ($number==10) && ($x==10) ){
                 $myClassName = "table__star full";
                }
                echo'<span class='. $myClassName .'></span>';
            }
            ?>
            <span class="table__cell-text"><span class="table__val"><?php echo $number; ?></span><span class="table__sum">/10</span></span>
        </td>
```

Это код который формирует звездочки рейтинга. Если рейтинг задан <10 то я хочу добавлять класс `table__star disactive` если поставлен рейтинг 10.. то у последнего span  должен быть класс `table__star full` Оно вроде как и работает, но неправильно. Второй класс оно отображает как атрибут при выводе, а не как класс html. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять, и кавычки менял и как конкретизацию делал. Объясните, что не так делаю ?

Comment: `<span class="'. $myClassName .'"></span>`

Comment: @splash58 а лучше без конкатенаций обойтись

Comment: Есть как минимум три варианта. Если человек понимает, что делает, по мне все равно, как он это делает